# Storing video files in database

Tags: android

I have an application containing database with pictures. I also wanted the database to contain some videos. Is it possible to store videos in database by converting them to byte array or other format?

Comment: Would you not just store the filename?

Comment: Isn't the app database in /data? Which means that those videos will consume space from the main memory, rather than the sd card?

Answer (score 4):

You could store a binary object within a database, but why bother? Simply store the path/file name to the pictures/videos.

Comment: I can do that. But just wanted to know if there is a way to store videos too in db.

Comment: It's for sending / downloading the database rows via internet and be able to get the file data in the other side and not just a path

Answer (score 0):

The mediastore content provider has a standard way of doing this. On this page look for MediaStore

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

The example is for images, but if you get the mime type right and write the data to the stream correctly it should work.